Issues with Dart Class for MikroTik Router Connection: Unable to Send and Receive Commands
I'm working on a Dart application to connect to a MikroTik router using its API. The connection to the router is established successfully, but I encounter issues when sending commands and receiving data. Below is the code for my RouterConnection class.
dart

// (Insert your code here)
Problem:

When I establish a connection, it successfully connects to the MikroTik router, but I cannot send commands or receive data.

After connecting, the login process does not seem to complete, and I'm unable to retrieve any response from the router.


Code Overview:

The RouterConnection class manages the connection to the MikroTik router.

The connect method attempts to log in using the provided credentials.

The write method sends commands to the router, and the read method listens for responses.


Specific Questions:

What could be causing the failure in sending or receiving data after establishing the connection?

Are there any common mistakes in handling socket connections in Dart that I should be aware of?

How can I ensure that the commands I send are correctly formatted for the MikroTik API?

Is the login response handling correctly implemented, and how can I troubleshoot if it fails?


Additional Information:

I am using Dart's Socket class to manage the connection.

The router's API is expected to respond with a confirmation after the login command is sent.


Any guidance or suggestions on resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated!
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

/// This class manages a connection to a MikroTik router, allowing commands to be sent and responses to be read.
class RouterConnection {
  final String ip; // Router IP address
  final int port; // Router port (default is 8728 for API)
  Socket? socket; // Socket for the connection
  bool connected = false; // Indicates if the connection is successful
  final int timeout; // Timeout for connection attempts
  final int attempts; // Number of connection attempts
  final int delay; // Delay between attempts

  RouterConnection({
    required this.ip,
    required this.port,
    this.timeout = 5,
    this.attempts = 3,
    this.delay = 2,
  });

  /// Connects to the router and logs in with the provided credentials. It retries based on `attempts`.
  Future<bool> connect(String login, String password) async {
    for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= attempts; attempt++) {
      print('Connection attempt #$attempt to $ip:$port...');
      try {
        socket = await Socket.connect(ip, port, timeout: Duration(seconds: timeout));
        print('Connected to $ip:$port');

        // Send login command
        await write('/login');
        await write('=name=$login', false);

        // Read response
        List<String> response = await read();

        // Check the response
        if (response.isNotEmpty) {
          if (response[0] == '!trap') {
            print('Login failed: ${response[1]}');
            return false;
          } else if (response[0].startsWith('=ret=')) {
            String challenge = response[0].substring(5);
            String responseHash = _generateResponseHash(password, challenge);
            await write('=response=$responseHash');

            // Read the second response
            List<String> secondResponse = await read();
            if (secondResponse.isNotEmpty && secondResponse[0] == '!done') {
              connected = true;
              print('Login successful');
              break;
            } else {
              print('Login failed: ${secondResponse[0]}');
            }
          }
        }

        // Close the connection if login fails
        socket?.destroy();
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: delay));

      } catch (e) {
        print('Connection failed: $e');
      }
    }

    return connected;
  }

  // Sends data to the router
  Future<void> write(String word, [bool terminate = true]) async {
    if (socket == null) {
      print('Socket is not initialized');
      return;
    }

    Uint8List encodedWord = _encodeWord(word);
    socket!.add(encodedWord);
    if (terminate) {
      socket!.add(Uint8List.fromList([0])); // Send zero word to indicate end of command
    }
    await socket!.flush();
  }

  // Reads the response from the router
  Future<List<String>> read() async {
    if (socket == null) {
      print('Socket is not initialized');
      return [];
    }

    List<String> response = [];
    Completer<List<String>> completer = Completer();
    socket!.listen((Uint8List data) {
      String decodedResponse = utf8.decode(data);
      List<String> words = decodedResponse.split('\n');
      response.addAll(words);
      if (words.contains('!done') || words.contains('!trap')) {
        completer.complete(response);
      }
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  // Generates the MD5 hash for login
  String _generateResponseHash(String password, String challenge) {
    final challengeBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(challenge));
    final passwordBytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(password));
    final combined = Uint8List(1 + passwordBytes.length + challengeBytes.length);
    combined[0] = 0;
    combined.setRange(1, passwordBytes.length + 1, passwordBytes);
    combined.setRange(passwordBytes.length + 1, combined.length, challengeBytes);

    final hash = md5.convert(combined).toString();
    return '00$hash';
  }

  // Encodes words according to the MikroTik protocol
  Uint8List _encodeWord(String word) {
    final wordBytes = utf8.encode(word);
    final int len = wordBytes.length;
    late Uint8List encodedLen;

    if (len <= 0x7F) {
      encodedLen = Uint8List(1)..[0] = len;
    } else if (len <= 0x3FFF) {
      encodedLen = Uint8List(2)
        ..[0] = (len >> 8) | 0x80
        ..[1] = len & 0xFF;
    } else if (len <= 0x1FFFFF) {
      encodedLen = Uint8List(3)
        ..[0] = (len >> 16) | 0xC0
        ..[1] = (len >> 8) & 0xFF
        ..[2] = len & 0xFF;
    } else {
      encodedLen = Uint8List(4)
        ..[0] = (len >> 24) | 0xE0
        ..[1] = (len >> 16) & 0xFF
        ..[2] = (len >> 8) & 0xFF
        ..[3] = len & 0xFF;
    }

    return Uint8List.fromList(encodedLen + wordBytes);
  }
}

void main() async {
  // Setup connection details
  String routerIp = '91e209389285.sn.mynetname.net'; // Router IP address
  int routerPort = 8728; // Router port (typically 8728 for API)
  String username = 'a'; // Username
  String password = '1234'; // Password

  // Create a connection to the router
  RouterConnection connection = RouterConnection(ip: routerIp, port: routerPort);

  // Attempt to connect and log in
  bool isConnected = await connection.connect(username, password);

  // Display the result
  if (isConnected) {
    print('Successfully logged in to the router at $routerIp:$routerPort');
  } else {
    print('Failed to log in to the router at $routerIp:$routerPort');
  }
}


You aren't listening to the socket correctly. As soon as you get connected, listen to the socket (once), with an onData that saves the received bytes. There's a useful class availalabe ( https://pub.dev/documentation/buffer/latest/buffer/ByteDataReader-class.html ) that allows you to add arbitrary chunks of bytes like you receive from the socket, then read them bit by bit.

You may find it easier to get started with the REST API.
